# Salesforce Connected App API Calling from Postman gives Error

Tags: salesforce

I have Created Connected App in Salesforce where I have received Client Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, and I have also generated Security Token

I am trying to test post request from Postman but getting error.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "authentication failure"
}
```

in App I have clicked on Require Secret for Web Server Flow = true, Selected OAuth Scopes currently I have selected All the options available

my post url is something like mentioned below

https://s********-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=3*************.9****p.***********&client_secret=33*********4&username=p*****@s******.com&password=$******9qs*********po

IP Relaxation = Relax IP restrictions

what am i missing? can anyone guide?

I have Created Connected App in SalesForce where I have received Client Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, and I have also generated Security Token

IP Relaxation = Relax IP restrictions

Answer (score 1):

I have done all the steps correctly, Issue was because in OAuth and OpenID Connect Settings Allow OAuth Username-Password Flows was not enabled